# Rails - display only certain columns based on user's input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm still fairly new to rails.  I have a Product model, the product has about 20 attributes, such as size, cost, country, etc.  Instead of showing all of the attributes I'd like to allow the user to select the attributes he/she is interested in and display only those.

What would be best practice for implementing this in rails 4?

Comment: Why not only display the inputs when they have value? `<%= product.country unless product.country.blank? %>`

Comment: @KenStipek Showing or not showing the info is not based on the existence of the information, rather on if the user is interested in seeing it.  In other words, product.country = USA, but the user is only interested in product.size.

Comment: Is the decision to show the item based one what a user entered into the system when the product was created, or a user setting?

Comment: @KenStipek it will be based on the user's selection.  Something similar to how you can limit your search results on Kayak.  Show me only flights that depart before noon, or that cost less than $100, etc.  Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a list of checkbox that user can click and see a specific set of values. 
This can be achieved using by simple jquery click() functionality. Ex-
Lets say user only wants to 5 attributes, so he checks the 5 attributes of his choice by click the corresponding check boxes - shipping cost, amount, qty, discount and color.
You can have  jquery click event which will be invoked when customer selects the checkbox and display the values.

Ex -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if($(this).attr("checked"))
        {
            //Display attribute
             product.cost
        }

    });
});
```